# How to lock the app in 5 minutes after entering to background

Tags: ios, swift

If my app has been in background for more than 5 minutes, I want to perform the navigation to lock screen view controller. Here is my code. But sometimes it works, as it should, and sometimes it does not work. How can it be fixed?

```
private var lockTimer: Timer?

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    lockTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 300, repeats: false) { _ in
        // Navigation code
    }
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    lockTimer?.invalidate()
    lockTimer = nil
}
```

Comment: one alternative was there you can store timestamp in user default and when you come back you can compare that timestamp with current time and you can do your logic. sometime above logic not worked

Answer (score 2):

Background tasks are not guaranteed to run on iOS for very long. There are ways to improve your chances of completing your background task detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) or [here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/finite-length-tasks-in-background-ios-swift-60f2db4fa01b).

An alternative way you can implement this is by saving the time (say in the user defaults) the app enters the background and then when the app opens again, you check the time and move to the lock screen if it has been over 5 minutes.

Comment: Then it becomes possible to bypass the app lock screen by changing the system date and time.

Comment: You just add another check then. If what you stored in user defaults is in the future then you just lock the screen. If you need better security to protect against the user changing the system time then you should just lock the screen every time the user leaves the app. Alternatively, if your app requires an internet connection you can check the stored time against a server returned time.

Answer (score -1):

Try below approach:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "LastInactiveDate")
    defaults.synchronize()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let lastInactiveDate = defaults.object(forKey: "LastInactiveDate") as? Date{
        let seconds = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastInactiveDate)
        print("Seconds ::" , seconds)
        if seconds >= 300{
            //Do any thing here to lock the app
        }
    }
    defaults.set(nil, forKey: "LastInactiveDate")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Note: Apple docs for `UserDefaults`: ***synchronize()**
Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.*